# Python 3.3 cgi: Cannot decode GET parameter with value %A3

Tags: python, http, encoding, cgi

I am really struggling to find an answer to this.

I am writing a simple cgi script and the input GET parameters will be html encoded
e.g. `£ -> %A3`

Here 2 test URLs im using in my browser.

> ?a=%7B&b=%A3
>
> ?a={&b=£

When i loop through the parameters from cgi.FieldStorage i get an exception with the b parameter.
- i know its related to encodign of some form, but i just can't work out a solution.

```
key = a
value = {

key = b
```

> ERROR: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)

```
key = a
value = {

key = b
```

> ERROR: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa3' in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)

The following is the test CGI script.

```
#!/opt/python-3.3.4/bin/python3
import cgitb
import cgi
import sys

print("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8")
print("")


print("<html>")
print("<body>")
print("<h1>Hello</h1>")

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
#form = cgi.FieldStorage(encoding="utf8")

for i in form.keys():
   print("<br>key = ", i)
   try:
      tmp   = form[i].value
      print("<br>value = %s" % tmp)
   except Exception as err:
      print("<br>ERROR:", err)

print("</body>")
print("</html>")
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that GET only supports ASCII characters.
Therefore you need to use POST for non-ASCII characters